# Retaining self with nested blocks?

Tags: ios, objective-c, scope, automatic-ref-counting, objective-c-blocks

With the following code:

```
@interface MyClass()
{
   NSMutableArray * dataArray;
}
@end

@implementation MyClass

- (void) doSomething
{
    __typeof__(self) __weak wself = self;
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0,0), ^{
       __typeof__(self) sself = wself;
       [sself->dataArray addObject: @"Hello World"];

       dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
         [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval: 30];

         UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: sself->dataArray[0] 
                                                         message: @"Message"
                                                        delegate: nil
                                               cancelButtonTitle: @"OK"
                                               otherButtonTitles: nil];
         [alert show];
       });
    });
}

@end
```

1. Is this the proper way to access `sself` from within the main queue block?
2. Would `sself` go out of scope once the initial queue finished?
3. Should I add a second `__typeof__(self) sself = wself;` inside the main queue block?

Comment: By the way, it's probably worth noting that in this particular example, you don't have to do this `weakSelf`/`strongSelf` pattern if you don't want. Where you really want to do this is where you have potential strong reference cycles. But unlike your other question, there is no potential strong reference cycle here. You may certainly do this `weakSelf`/`strongSelf` dance if that's what makes sense for your app (if you're really concerned about the object being retained while the code represented by `sleepForTimeInterval` is running), but it's worth noting that you don't have to in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ask:

> Is this the proper way to access `sself` from within the main queue block?

Almost. You also should be checking to make sure `sself` is not `nil`, too. You do this because dereferencing a ivar for an `nil` pointer may crash your app. Thus, check to make sure it's not `nil`:

```
- (void) doSomething
{
    typeof(self) __weak wself = self;
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0,0), ^{
       typeof(self) sself = wself;
       if (sself) {
           [sself->dataArray addObject: @"Hello World"];

           dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
             [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval: 30];

             UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: sself->dataArray[0] 
                                                             message: @"Message"
                                                            delegate: nil
                                                   cancelButtonTitle: @"OK"
                                                   otherButtonTitles: nil];
             [alert show];
           });
        }
    });
}
```

You then ask:

> Would `sself` go out of scope once the initial queue finished?

It goes out of scope, but is retained by the inner block and will be retained until that inner block finishes.

> Should I add a second `__typeof__(self) sself = wself;` inside the main queue block?

You can if you want to, but it's not necessary. It depends upon the desired behavior. If, for example, you want to see this alert even if the current object (presumably a view controller) is dismissed, then use `sself` pattern (because you presumably want to hang on to it so you have access to `dataArray`). If you don't want to show the alert anymore, then you'd repeat this `weakSelf`/`strongSelf` dance.

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes, sure it is.
2. No, you'll be able to use in main_queue block.
3. No, you don't have to. You don't have to add `__typeof__(self) sself = wself;` even in global_queue block; it's not necessary, you already have a weakened self object `wself` (moreover, you will retain `self` in `__typeof__(self)` part inside the block).
4. You don't have to use `__typeof__`. Use simply `typeof(self)`